# False Compile Error End If without block If

Tags: excel, vba

I have researched stack overflow for answers but it seems like all questions had the compiler being correct, except in my case the compiler seems to be wrong.

I have two block ifs and one one-liner if as in this code:

```
Function GetBOMEntriesWithoutRM() As Variant
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim search_rng, error_range, result_range, result As range
    Dim dict As New Dictionary
    
    On Error GoTo Fail
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set tbl = sht.ListObjects(1)
        
        If tbl.Name Like "tbBOM*" Then
            Set result_rng = tbl.ListColumns("Item").DataBodyRange
            Set search_rng = tbl.ListColumns("RMIndex").DataBodyRange
            Set error_rng = search_rng.Find(What:=CVErr(xlErrNA), LookIn:=xlValues)
            
            If Not error_rng Is Nothing Then
                Do
                    Set result = Intersect(error_rng.EntireRow, result_rng)
                    If Not dict.Exists(result.Cells(1)) Then dict.Add result.Cells(1), result.Cells(1)
                While Not error_rng Is Nothing
            End If
            
        End If
    Next sht
    
    GetBOMEntriesWithoutRM = dict.Items()
    Exit Function
    
Fail:
    GetBOMEntriesWithoutRM = 0
    
End Function
```

You can see that there's two distinct `End If`s to go with the two block Ifs and there's no overlapping scopes.

I tried removing the first `End If` that seems to trigger the error but then I get the opposite error of 'Block If without End If'.

I tried changing the deep nested one-line `If` to a `block If` and that didn't help either.

I'm mindblown by this. I even restarted my Excel and my PC and still I get the same compile error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Loop` is missing before `While`.

```vb
                Do
                    Set result = Intersect(error_rng.EntireRow, result_rng)
                    If Not dict.Exists(result.Cells(1)) Then dict.Add result.Cells(1), result.Cells(1)
                Loop While Not error_rng Is Nothing
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Do...Loop statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/doloop-statement?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

---

- `search_rng, error_range, result_range` are declared as `Variant` instead of `Range` object.

```
Dim search_rng, error_range, result_range, result As range
```

Please chage it to

```
Dim search_rng As Range, error_range As Range, result_range As Range, result As Range
```

---

- `Option Explicit` is so important for VBA coding. `error_range, result_range` are in `Dim` clause. But you use `error_rng, result_rng` in the following code.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Option Explicit statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008808)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: I was wondering for a long time why I get a lot of type mismatches. This now makes a lot more sense: `Dim search_rng, error_range, result_range, result As range`. I use explicit mode when the code is too complex, however, I skip it when writing small pieces of code. Thanks a whole bunch.